# Load xml into mysql table with element

Tags: mysql, xml, linux, load

I am trying to load an xml file in a table. The issue is that XML elements are being inserted into the table together with their data.

Here is the table fields:

programname
programurl
catalogname
lastupdated
name
keywords
description
sku
manufacturer
manufacturerid,
upc
currency
price
buyurl
impressionurl
imageurl
advertisercategory
promotionaltext
instock

Here is my code

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/public_html/apw.xml' INTO TABLE 
apw ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n';
(id,
programname,
programurl,
catalogname,
lastupdated,
name,
keywords,
description,
sku,
manufacturer,
manufacturerid,
upc,
currency,
price,
buyurl,
impressionurl,
imageurl,
advertisercategory,
promotionaltext,
instock);
```

So for instance, the field programname got inserted with data of
"Auto Parts Warehouse" instead of "Auto Parts Warehouse"
and programurl "url" instead of "url"
What iam i doing wrong>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after `FIELDS TERMINATED ...`

You should use the `LOAD XML ...` Syntax, too. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html:

```
The LOAD XML statement reads data from an XML file into a table
```

Your `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` is used to load a flat-file (csv) to a table, not a XML:

```
The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table
```